# изменение или смена, как правильно?

Tags: выбор-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать: изменение направление движения или смена направления движения? В контексте: когда игрок в процессе перемещения резко разворачивается и начинает движение в противоположную сторону. или резко поворачивает направо, в зависимости от положения игрока - соперника. Например: подсчет действий высокой интенсивности (HIE) за минуту игры, а именно ускорений, торможений и количества изменений направления движения. Или нужно количества смен направления движений?

Comment: Подсчет количества событий высокой интенсивности за минуту игры(HIE per min), а именно: ускорений, торможений, событий с резкой сменой направления движения/вектора направления движения.